# Django models foreign key validation

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django models:

```py
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)


class GoForAWalk(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.CharField()

    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)
    dog = models.ForeignKey(Dog)
```

I want that a `Owner` can only `GoForAWalk` with one of his own `Dog`.

Currently any owner can go for a walk with any dog.

Would you restrict this via model validators or via some logic during the creation of a new `GoForAWalk` object?

Can anyone provide an example? I'm quite stuck.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Philipp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GoForAWalk` doesn't need an `owner` as it "comes with" a `dog`, so if the dog goes for a walk you already know with whom. Just remove `owner` from `GoForAWalk`. This will fix possible inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the validation in **full_clean** method of your model:

```py
class GoForAWalk(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.CharField()

    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)
    dog = models.ForeignKey(Dog)

    def full_clean(self, **kwargs):
        super().full_clean(**kwargs)
    
        if self.dog.owner != self.owner:
            raise ValidationError(...)
```

Some information about full_clean: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean

With last Django version it is probably possible to make something with new Model Constraint: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects